# How to extract jsonb from Postgresql to Spring webflux using R2dbc

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-webflux, jsonb, r2dbc

So I had this idea that's way over my head really since I've only been programming for a short while but I wanted to build a reactive Spring webflux app that exposes json endpoints to a react frontend.

The problem started when I decided to use the jsonb format in Postgres because I thought I might use json all the way from the DB up until the frontend layer.

When I try to SELECT the table with jsonb using the reactive R2dbc drivers I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 3802 is not a valid object id
```

I have a table in postgres that looks like this:

```
Column  |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |           Default
---------+---------+-----------+----------+------------------------------
 id      | integer |           | not null | generated always as identity
 details | jsonb   |           |          |
Indexes:
    "snacks_new_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

So if I extract this as text to Spring webflux it works fine since it's no longer json.

```
"SELECT id, details->>'name' as NAME, details->>'price' AS PRICE, details->>'quantity' AS QUANTITY FROM snacks_new"
```

I've seen some examples on how to convert jsonb to an json object using the older blocking drivers but I can't get the same to work with the newer non-blocking ones, I can't access them in any way.

So I have 2 questions really, how can I SELECT a table that contains jsonb using reactive drivers, and am I wasting my time trying to do this, is extracting the json as text and creating a normal POJO from it enough?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update: Please upgrade to R2DBC Postgres 0.8.0.RC1.

The driver added [recently](https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-postgresql/pull/161) support for JSON and JSONB types. You can consume JSON either as `String`, `byte[]` or `io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.Json` type:

```
// Read as Json
connection.createStatement("SELECT my_json FROM my_table")
        .execute()
        .flatMap(it -> it.map((row, rowMetadata) -> row.get("my_json", Json.class)))
        .map(Json::asString)

// Read as String
connection.createStatement("SELECT my_json FROM my_table")
        .execute()
        .flatMap(it -> it.map((row, rowMetadata) -> row.get("my_json", String.class)))

// Write JSON
connection.createStatement("INSERT INTO my_table (my_json) VALUES($1)")
        .bind("$1", Json.of("{\"hello\": \"world\"}"))
        .execute()

// Write JSON as String using ::JSON casting
connection.createStatement("INSERT INTO my_table (my_json) VALUES($1::JSON)")
        .bind("$1", "{\"hello\": \"world\"}")
        .execute()
```

Please note that when you want to bind JSON values for a `SELECT`, `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, then you must either use the driver `Json` type or cast the binding value with `$1::JSON` to JSON.

You can also provide your own `JsonCodec` implementation leveraging the driver's `CodecRegistrar` if you e.g. want to use GSON or Jackson to map serialize/deserialize values on the driver level.

References:

- [JSON support in `r2dbc-postgresql`](https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-postgresql#jsonjsonb-support)
- [Registering own `Codec`](https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-postgresql#extension-mechanism)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Of course support is added 2 weeks after I struggled so much haha.

Answer (score 9):

As explained by [@mp911de](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2067527/mp911de), R2DBC now includes a Codec for **Json**. But defining your entity attributes as `String`, `byte[]` is not very comfortable and type `io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.Json` is not very portable. Moreover you'll need to define a custom serializer/deserializer if you want to use it in a REST API as explained in the references.

One better option is to define a custom converter `io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.Json` from/to `JsonNode` and use this later type for your attributes:

```
@Configuration
public class ReactivePostgresConfig {

private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

public ReactivePostgresConfig(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
}

@Bean
public R2dbcCustomConversions customConversions() {
    List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
    converters.add(new JsonToJsonNodeConverter(objectMapper));
    converters.add(new JsonNodeToJsonConverter(objectMapper));
    return R2dbcCustomConversions.of(PostgresDialect.INSTANCE, converters);
}

@ReadingConverter
static class JsonToJsonNodeConverter implements Converter<Json, JsonNode> {
    
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JsonToJsonNodeConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }
    
    @Override
    public JsonNode convert(Json json) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readTree(json.asString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("Problem while parsing JSON: {}", json, e);
        }
        return objectMapper.createObjectNode();
    }
}

@WritingConverter
static class JsonNodeToJsonConverter implements Converter<JsonNode, Json> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JsonNodeToJsonConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Json convert(JsonNode source) {
        try {
            return Json.of(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(source));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            LOG.error("Error occurred while serializing map to JSON: {}", source, e);
        }
        return Json.of("");
    }
}
}
```

References:

- [Mapping to JSON Fields with Spring Data R2DBC and Reactive Postgres Driver](https://medium.com/@nikola.babic1/mapping-to-json-fields-with-spring-data-r2dbc-and-reactive-postgres-driver-1db765067dc5). Check the new way of registering converters in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66983206/3971900).
- [How to define custom serializers for io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.Json](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/docs/pg.md)

Comment: Thanks for the extension, I have a question. Do these converters are only relevant to either native invocations or have integration with Spring Data R2DBC too?

Comment: I don't understand very well the question. Those are Spring Data converters used automatically by spring-data to map between R2DBC types and DTO attributes.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was defining bad the R2dbcCustomConversions

Comment: Are the `@WritingConverter` and `@ReadingConverter` annotations reversed?
Wouldn't you be reading JsonNode from the db to Json in the app, and writing from Json to JsonNode in the DB?

Comment: @Jolley71717 They are ok, it's the opposite: `io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.Json` is what it gets from db, but you want JsonNode in the app.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

As of time of writing (sept 15, 2019) they did not support JSON, but now they do support JSON from version 0.8.0 and beyond

**Old answer:**

Im sorry to say that i think you are, as you put it, *wasting your time*.

when looking at the [github](https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-postgresql) for the R2DBC drivers you can see in their table, of what they support, that json is as of now, **not supported**.