# R2dbc custom converter

Tags: spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

How can I add my custom converter to mu spring boot application?
My entity field

```
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(value = "create_time")
    private Instant createTime;
```

My converters are

```
    @Bean
    public Converter<Long, Instant> longInstantConverter() {
        return new Converter<Long, Instant>() {
            @Override
            public Instant convert(Long source) {
                return Instant.ofEpochMilli(source);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Converter<Instant, Long> instantLongConverter() {
        return new Converter<Instant, Long>() {
            @Override
            public Long convert(@NotNull Instant source) {
                return source.toEpochMilli();
            }
        };
    }
```

I have an exception

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Could not read property @org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Column(value=create_time) @org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate()private java.time.Instant com.example.database.model.MyTable.createTime from result set!
.........
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Long] to type [java.time.Instant]
........
```

How can I fix it, please help me!

Answer (score 12):

You need to register the converters with R2DBC:

```
@Bean
public R2dbcCustomConversions customConversions() {
    List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
    converters.add(new SomeReadConverter());
    converters.add(new SomeWriteConverter());
    return R2dbcCustomConversions.of(MySqlDialect.INSTANCE, converters);
    // deprecated: return new R2dbcCustomConversions(converters);
}
```

You don't need to override the whole R2dbcConfiguration.

Comment: yeah that works. In new version of r2dbc constructor R2dbcCustomerConversions(converters) is deprecated, so from now we should use:
R2dbcCustomConversions.of(SqlServerDialect.INSTANCE, converters)
where you need to choose correct dialect for your DB

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why they force the implementer to specify the dialect. Things getting more complicated.

Comment: It works, just one thing to keep in mind: BlockHound sees this converters as a blocking.

Comment: @Moler There*s nothing blocking in this code. Of course you need non blocking implementations of the converters itself also. You should post a separate question with your blocking details.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Works just perfect!

Answer (score 4):

Try to create `ReadingConverter` and `WritingConverter` respectively, and register them in the Config file.

```java
public class DatabaseConfig extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {
    //...
    
    @Override
    protected List<Object> getCustomConverters() {
        return List.of(
                new PostReadingConverter(),
                new PostStatusWritingConverter()
        );
    }
}
```

Check the complete codes [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/data-r2dbc-repositories/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DatabaseConfig.java#L48-L55).

For Spring Boot applications, try to [override the default beans](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/boot/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java#L236), or create a `R2dbcCustomConversions`.

```java
@Bean
public R2dbcCustomConversions r2dbcCustomConversions(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    var dialect = DialectResolver.getDialect(connectionFactory);
    var converters = List.of(
               ...
    );
    return R2dbcCustomConversions.of(dialect, converters);
}
```

Comment: is there anyway not to override the connection factory?

Comment: How to handle the `Converter<Json, Optional<T>`?  If T is ClassA, ClassB, it only work with ClassA.

Comment: @RamPrakash Create a `R2dbcCustomConversions` instead.